# Checkerframework replace annotation

Tags: java, annotations, checker-framework

I'm new to Checker Framework and I have defined 2 subtyping annotations like this:

```
@Target(value={TYPE_USE,TYPE_PARAMETER})
@DefaultQualifierInHierarchy
@SubtypeOf(value={})
public @interface Base{}
```

and

```
@Target(value={TYPE_USE,TYPE_PARAMETER})
@SubtypeOf(value=Base.class)
@DefaultFor(value=LOWER_BOUND)
public @interface Sub{}
```

When I use a subtyping checker with these annotations on the following code, it produces an error, because sink() expects a string marked as @Sub, but receives @Base (the default for String s0), which is the expected behaviour.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s0 = "a";
    sink(s0);
}

public static void sink(@Sub String s) {}
```

Now I want to add a third annotation, called for example @ToSub and use it like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s0 = "a";
    @ToSub String s1 = s0;
    sink(s1);
}

public static void sink(@Sub String s) {}
```

This third annotation is supposed to turn the current type of s0 (@Base) into its subtype @Sub for the new string s1, so that this code example would not throw an error.

Is this at all possible with Checker Framework?
I could not find a way to accomplish this simply by defining a new annotation, did I miss something? Can this maybe only be accomplished by writing a completely new checker?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for Java's existing `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

More generally, if you want to suppress a warning, see the ["Suppressing warnings" chapter](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#suppressing-warnings) of the Checker Framework manual.

Comment: Basically yes, but I don't want to explicitly have to write `@SuppressWarnings("subtyping")` in my code. Instead I want to declare a new annotation, in this example `@ToSub`, which has the same functionality as the subtype `@Sub` but also suppresses the warning. Using `@SuppressWarnings` as a meta-annotation for `@ToSub` doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: How about creating a `toSub` method that takes a `@Base` and returns its argument as a `@Sub`?  (You would write `@SuppressWarnings` on its definition, and a Java compiler is smart enough to optimize it away.  Then you can write `String s1 = toSub(s0)`.

Comment: That would work, but I specifically want to use a custom annotation to accomplish this, because I want to use this functionality together with a compiler plugin I have written, which also uses that same custom annotation.

Comment: To do that, define a type hierarchy that includes all 3 qualifiers and override `commonAssignmentCheck` in your checker's visitor class.